# My localhost/H2-console doesn't create my tables

Tags: java, spring, maven, console, h2

Yoo Codeers,
have issue with **h2-console** if i create table in java and open h2-console on port what i using, so i don't see my tables,i following one video,but for me doesn't work.

**POM**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>sk.wynny</groupId>
    <artifactId>springLearn</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>springLearn</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**MOVIE CLASS**

```
package sk.wynny.model;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
public class Movie {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "movie_director",joinColumns =
    @JoinColumn(name = "movie_id"),inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name ="director_id" ))
    Set<Director> movieSet = new HashSet<>();




    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Movie() {
    }
}
```

**Basic Class **

```
package sk.wynny.springlearn;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringLearnApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringLearnApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

**app properties** - from following video what i see, he doesnt use log info,he just use *spring.h2.console.enabled=true* and for him was worked,i try many options simply like that (but,can't connect to my h2-console,cause error),or like this bellow.. i connect to my h2 DB,but didnt see my tables.

```
   server.port=8080
    spring.h2.console.enabled=true
    spring.datasource.platform=h2
    spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:wynny
    
    spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
    spring.jpa.show-sql=true
    spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
    spring.datasource.username=wynny
```

Have some tips how repair it ? :D
Director class is not included in this post,is same like MOVIES.

Answer (score 0):

**AFTER RUN**

```
2022-02-13 15:03:22.146  INFO 13392 --- [           main] s.w.springlearn.SpringLearnApplication   : Starting SpringLearnApplication using Java 17.0.1 on DESKTOP-K3O8I67 with PID 13392 (C:\Users\Patrik Severín\IdeaProjects\springLearn\target\classes started by Wynny in C:\Users\Patrik Severín\IdeaProjects\springLearn)
2022-02-13 15:03:22.148  INFO 13392 --- [           main] s.w.springlearn.SpringLearnApplication   : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2022-02-13 15:03:22.923  INFO 13392 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2022-02-13 15:03:22.940  INFO 13392 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 6 ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
2022-02-13 15:03:23.589  INFO 13392 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2022-02-13 15:03:23.599  INFO 13392 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2022-02-13 15:03:23.600  INFO 13392 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.56]
2022-02-13 15:03:23.704  INFO 13392 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2022-02-13 15:03:23.704  INFO 13392 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1509 ms
2022-02-13 15:03:23.739  INFO 13392 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2022-02-13 15:03:23.931  INFO 13392 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2022-02-13 15:03:23.943  INFO 13392 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.h2.H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration    : H2 console available at '/h2-console'. Database available at 'jdbc:h2:file:C:\Users\Patrik Severín\IdeaProjects\springLearn/data/sample'
2022-02-13 15:03:24.095  INFO 13392 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2022-02-13 15:03:24.143  INFO 13392 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.6.4.Final
2022-02-13 15:03:24.298  INFO 13392 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2022-02-13 15:03:24.433  INFO 13392 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
2022-02-13 15:03:24.624  INFO 13392 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2022-02-13 15:03:24.634  INFO 13392 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2022-02-13 15:03:24.674  WARN 13392 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2022-02-13 15:03:24.930  WARN 13392 --- [           main] ion$DefaultTemplateResolverConfiguration : Cannot find template location: classpath:/templates/ (please add some templates or check your Thymeleaf configuration)
2022-02-13 15:03:25.045  INFO 13392 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2022-02-13 15:03:25.057  INFO 13392 --- [           main] s.w.springlearn.SpringLearnApplication   : Started SpringLearnApplication in 3.292 seconds (JVM running for 3.695)
```

**h2 console write this**

```
Database "mem:testdb" not found, either pre-create it or allow remote database creation (not recommended in secure environments) [90149-200] 90149/90149 (Help)
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLNonTransientConnectionException: Database "mem:testdb" not found, either pre-create it or allow remote database creation (not recommended in secure environments) [90149-200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:622)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:429)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:205)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:181)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:71)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:192)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSessionAndValidate(Engine.java:171)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Engine.java:166)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Engine.java:29)
    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectEmbeddedOrServer(SessionRemote.java:340)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:173)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:152)
    at org.h2.Driver.connect(Driver.java:69)
    at org.h2.util.JdbcUtils.getConnection(JdbcUtils.java:309)
    at org.h2.util.JdbcUtils.getConnection(JdbcUtils.java:289)
    at org.h2.server.web.WebServer.getConnection(WebServer.java:785)
    at org.h2.server.web.WebApp.login(WebApp.java:1008)
    at org.h2.server.web.WebApp.process(WebApp.java:223)
    at org.h2.server.web.WebApp.processRequest(WebApp.java:173)
    at org.h2.server.web.WebServlet.doGet(WebServlet.java:129)
    at org.h2.server.web.WebServlet.doPost(WebServlet.java:166)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:895)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1732)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).